Exception has occurred. Error in accessing saved model
I recieve this error when calling my fine-tuned GPT2 saved model. Exception has occurred: OSError
Error no file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.index or flax_model.msgpack found in directory ./results/checkpoint-21264.
Even though if i run the same code on google colab it works fine but in VS code it results in the error.
I tried updating transformers but that didnt work. do i need to download these files from hugging face?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

ok so I have solved the problem if any one faced the same thing and wants to solve it, the solution is to download theses files from hugging face
